# Reference request: a definition of the ``directional convex hull''

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

The ordinary convex hull $\text{conv} A$ of a set $A$ in Euclidean space may be defined as the intersection of all convex supersets of $A$. Suppose I wish to restrict the permissible supersets as follows:

**Definition.** Let $A,D\subset\mathbb{R^n}$. The D-directional convex hull $\text{conv}_D A$ is the intersection of all convex supersets of $A$ with an outer normal in $D\setminus\{0\}$ at every point on their boundary. (By the outer normal I mean the normal of a supporting hyperplane.)

Has this concept been studied before? If so, under which name?

It is different from the [orientation-restricted convex hull](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020025596000564).